# Twitter widget android

Tags: twitter, android-widget

Is there anyone now how to make widget like twitter? 
They have 2 layout and user can user one of them after they see the layout.
Thank u very much..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a tutorial to do the sending part. It uses OAuth for the Twitter authentication: http://www.androidacademy.com/3-tutorials/43-hands-on/249-twitterwidget-how-to-write-an-android-widget-which-tweets